# Table and TikZ object on two columns

Tags: tables, minipage

I'm trying to have a table generated by the tabular environment and a plot generated by TikZ placed side by side. I tried using the table and minipage environment since it works for having multiple tables side by side. However the two objects seems to be off vertically, what am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{5 cm}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
   \hline                       
   Temperature & IQ Score \\ \hline
   14\celsius & 57\% \\ \hline
   16\celsius & 65\% \\ \hline
   18\celsius & 69\% \\ \hline
   20\celsius & 71\% \\ \hline
   22\celsius & 79\% \\ \hline
   24\celsius & 88\% \\ \hline
   26\celsius & 81\% \\ \hline
   28\celsius & 76\% \\ \hline
   30\celsius & 66\% \\ \hline
   32\celsius & 62\% \\ 
   \hline  
  \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \hspace{1cm} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{10cm}
  \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[grid=major, grid style={dashed,gray!30}, xlabel=Temperature $\celsius$,ylabel=IQ Scores \%, legend style={at={(axis cs:25,28)},anchor=south}]
   %\addplot[scatter, only marks, scatter/classes={y={black}}] table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {NumbersAndFunctions-Temp-IQ-data.csv};
   \addplot[color=red, domain=7:41, thick, samples=400, mark=none] {88*exp(-(\x-24)^2/253.0889)};
   \legend{Raw, Gaussian};
   \end{axis}   
   \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) you are much more likely to get help if you post a full minimal example instead of just a sniplet. That is something people can copy and run immediately without having to add anything. In your example we for example does not know where  `\celsius` comes from.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154422/1952) to  "Vertical align a tabular and tikz figure in a minipage" help you?

Comment: @daleif Ah yes I'm sorry, should've paid more attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are  aligned at the top:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{5 cm}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
   \hline
   Temperature & IQ Score \\ \hline
   \SI{14}{\celsius} & \SI{57}{\percent} \\ \hline    %% change all \% like this
   \SI{16}{\celsius} & 65\% \\ \hline
   \SI{18}{\celsius} & 69\% \\ \hline
   \SI{20}{\celsius} & 71\% \\ \hline
   \SI{22}{\celsius} & 79\% \\ \hline
   \SI{24}{\celsius} & 88\% \\ \hline
   \SI{26}{\celsius} & 81\% \\ \hline
   \SI{28}{\celsius} & 76\% \\ \hline
   \SI{30}{\celsius} & 66\% \\ \hline
   \SI{32}{\celsius} & 62\% \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
   \hfill
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
   \begin{axis}[grid=major, grid style={dashed,gray!30}, xlabel=Temperature $\celsius$,ylabel=IQ Scores\si{\percent}, legend style={at={(axis cs:25,28)},anchor=south}]
   %\addplot[scatter, only marks, scatter/classes={y={black}}] table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {NumbersAndFunctions-Temp-IQ-data.csv};
   \addplot[color=red, domain=7:41, thick, samples=400, mark=none] {88*exp(-(\x-24)²/253.0889)};
   \addlegendentry{Raw,Gaussian};
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With no `[t]` in `minipage` and `[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]` in `tikzpicture` they are aligned at the center.

[image]

With no `[b`] in both `tabular` and `minipage` and `[baseline={(current bounding box.south)}]` in `tikzpicture` they are aligned at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Change all `65\%` etc similar to `\SI{57}{\percent}`. You can see the difference.

Comment: That makes sense now! Thank you for the help.