# Problem using TikZ and Paracol

Tags: tikz-pgf, paracol

I have several `TikZ` graphics on one page. To add a description on the right side of the graphics I use the `paracol` package (is there a better way to do this?).

As you can see on the picture below the last graphic doesn't fit on page 1. This even results in bad positioning of footnotes, e.g. footnote 1 should appear on page 1.

How can deal with this problem without adding `\newpage` manually?

[image]

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2} % left column
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
% help lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
% axis
\draw[thick,->,black!75] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[pos=0.97,left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\switchcolumn % right column
I'm a description.
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{2} % left column
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
% help lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
% axis
\draw[thick,->,black!75] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[pos=0.97,left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\switchcolumn % right column
I'm a description.\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{2} % left column
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
% help lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
% axis
\draw[thick,->,black!75] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[pos=0.97,left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\switchcolumn % right column
I'm a description.
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{2} % left column
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
% help lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
% axis
\draw[thick,->,black!75] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[pos=0.97,left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\switchcolumn % right column
I'm a description.\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

If you change the scale of the tikz pictures to 0.59 you can see the following

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like this with a `tabular` (although you will have to break manually) or `minipages`. Following I propose a solution with `tcolorbox`. Every pair figure+comment are enclosed inside a `tcolorbox`. Each figure is the `upperpart` and each comment its `lowerpart`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\footnotelayout{m}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{empty, sidebyside, notitle, lower separated=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
% help lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
% axis
\draw[thick,->,black!75] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[pos=0.97,left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower % right column
I'm a description.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
% help lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
% axis
\draw[thick,->,black!75] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[pos=0.97,left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower % right column
I'm a description.\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
% help lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
% axis
\draw[thick,->,black!75] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[pos=0.97,left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower % right column
I'm a description.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
% help lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
% axis
\draw[thick,->,black!75] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[pos=0.97,left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower % right column
I'm a description.\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The footnotes should appear on the end of the page, e.g. footnote 1 at the end of page 1 and footnote 2 at the end of page 2.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider Footnote problem can be solved with   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274/can-i-get-a-normal-footnote-in-a-minipage-environment-in-latex-how. You could also find alternative solutions to `figure`+`paragraph` pairs in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154401/vertical-align-a-tabular-and-tikz-figure-in-a-minipage